# sql query in the sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a login page on which are userid and password feeld, but I want to write the query for login when user can give username or emailid in userid textbox.

Answer (score 3):

That's a bit too vague. If you are just starting out, I'd recommend you look at the [login control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx). You could use this in conjunction with [the SQL Server Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998317.aspx) and not have to write any SQL yourself.